# Calling command from array with subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following code:

```
'''
Created by Baran Skistad, bjskistad on GitHub. 
Please give credit to Baran Skistad if you use this.
'''
index = 0
file = 'example.shs'
data = ''
loop = 0
loopString = ''
commands = ['']
command = 0
done = False
import subprocess

with open(file, 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

commands = [part + ';' for part in data[:-1].split(';')]
print commands
if done:
    while command <= len(commands):
        ccommand = commands[command]
        print ccommand[command][3:len(ccommand[command]-1)]
        subprocess.call([ccommand[3:len(commands[command]-1)]])
        command = command + 1
```

And it is giving me the following error:

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/source.py", line 23
    print ccommand[command][3:len(ccommand[command]-1)]
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


Process exited with code: 1
```

The `example.shs` file looks like this:

```
run rm wha;
run git clone https://github.com/jel-lang/jel.git;
```

As you can see, this is a custom language I made. What I want the Python file to do is take the first 4 letters and the last one off each item in the list and then run it using `subprocess`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is python 2 code, and you are running it with python 3. Run it with the command `python2` and you won't get that problem.